# Is there any reason why this cron job wouldn't be working

Tags: php, javascript, cron

EDIT: Cron line: /usr/bin/php /usr/local/yy/yy/yy/webspace/httpdocs/test.mysite.ie/test.php > /dev/null 2>&1

I have written a script that functions as it should when i navigate to it in the browser. This is my first time trying to use a cron job so i'm not overly familiar with how they work. The script is below. As i said, the script works as it should if i navigate to the url in a web browser.

test.php

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
//SET UP JS VARIABLES
var allMatchedNumbers = new Array();
var matchedthingyNumbers;
var matchedthingyPlus1Numbers;
var matchedthingyPlus2Numbers;
var winningthingyNumbers = new Array();
var winningBonusNumber;
var winningthingyPlus1Numbers = new Array();
var winningPlus1BonusNumber;
var winningthingyPlus2Numbers = new Array();
var winningPlus2BonusNumber;
var thingyList;
var thingyListItems;
var thingyPlus1List;
var thingyPlus1ListItems;
var thingyPlus2List;
var thingyPlus2ListItems;
var userNumbers = new Array();
var displayCounter = 1;
var drawDate;
var thingyNumbers;
var thingyBonus;
var thingyPlus1;
var thingyPlus1Bonus;
var thingyPlus2;
var thingyPlus2Bonus;

//GET RESULTS & DATE FOR thingy, PLUS1, PLUS2 FROM THE DOM OBJECT ONLY
$(document).ready(function fetchResults(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "scrape_page.php",
        success: function(data) {
        } 
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "latest_results.txt",
        success: function(data) {
            var dom = $(data);
            //GET thingy DATE
            drawDate = dom.find('.date-heading.fooRegular').contents().first().text();
            //GET thingy NUMBERS
            thingyNumbers = dom.find('.result-block').eq(0).find('.thingy-winning-numbers');
            thingyBonus = dom.find('.result-block').eq(0).find('.thingy-bonus');
            thingyPlus1 = dom.find('.result-block').eq(1).find('.thingy-winning-numbers');
            thingyPlus1Bonus = dom.find('.result-block').eq(1).find('.thingy-bonus');
            thingyPlus2 = dom.find('.result-block').eq(2).find('.thingy-winning-numbers');
            thingyPlus2Bonus = dom.find('.result-block').eq(2).find('.thingy-bonus');
            populateWinningNumbers();
        } 
    });
});


//PUT WINNING NUMBERS IN ARRAY
function populateWinningNumbers() {
    //MAIN thingy NUMBERS
    thingyList = thingyNumbers;
    thingyListItems = thingyList.find('li');
    thingyPlus1List = thingyPlus1;
    thingyPlus1ListItems = thingyPlus1List.find('li');
    thingyPlus2List = thingyPlus2;
    thingyPlus2ListItems = thingyPlus2List.find('li');

    thingyListItems.each(function(index) {
        winningthingyNumbers[index] = parseInt($(this).text());
    });
    //winningBonusNumber = parseInt($('#mainthingyBonus').find('li').text());
    winningBonusNumber = parseInt($(thingyBonus).find('li').text());
    winningthingyNumbers.push(winningBonusNumber);

    //thingy PLUS NUMBERS
    thingyPlus1ListItems.each(function(index) {
        winningthingyPlus1Numbers[index] = parseInt($(this).text());
    });
    winningPlus1BonusNumber = parseInt($(thingyPlus1Bonus).find('li').text());
    winningthingyPlus1Numbers.push(winningPlus1BonusNumber);
    //PLUS 2
    thingyPlus2ListItems.each(function(index) {
        winningthingyPlus2Numbers[index] = parseInt($(this).text());
    });
    winningPlus2BonusNumber = parseInt($(thingyPlus1Bonus).find('li').text());
    winningthingyPlus2Numbers.push(winningPlus2BonusNumber);

    postDataToDB();
}

//POST OFFICIAL thingy NUMBERS TO DATABASE
function postDataToDB() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "postToDB.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {thingyNums:winningthingyNumbers, thingyPlus1Nums: winningthingyPlus1Numbers, thingyPlus2Nums: winningthingyPlus2Numbers, drawDate:drawDate},
        // callback handler that will be called on success
        success: function (data) {
        }
    }); 
}
</script>
```

scrape_page.php

```
<?php

    include 'simple_html_dom.php';

    $html = file_get_html('http://www.site.com');
    $file = 'latest_results.txt';
    file_put_contents($file, $html);
?>
```

postToDB.php

```
<?php

$winningNums = $_POST['thingyNums'];
$winningPlus1Nums = $_POST['thingyPlus1Nums'];
$winningPlus2Nums = $_POST['thingyPlus2Nums'];
$drawDate = $_POST['drawDate'];

$thingyToSave = implode(',', $winningNums);
$plus1ToSave = implode(',', $winningPlus1Nums);
$plus2ToSave = implode(',', $winningPlus2Nums);

//CONNECT TO REMOTE
$con = mysql_connect("172.xx.xx.xx","user","pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

//SELECT thingy DB
mysql_select_db("App", $con);

//CHECK IF DATE ALREADY EXISTS IN DB
$date_check = mysql_query("SELECT drawDate FROM thingy WHERE drawDate='$drawDate'");
$do_date_check = mysql_num_rows($date_check);

if($do_date_check > 0){
    //DATE ALREADY IN DB
    die("Entries already exist");
} else {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO thingy (drawDate) VALUES ('$drawDate')");
    mysql_query("UPDATE thingy SET thingyRes = '$thingyToSave' WHERE drawDate = '$drawDate'");
    mysql_query("UPDATE thingy SET thingyPlus1Res = '$plus1ToSave' WHERE drawDate = '$drawDate'");
    mysql_query("UPDATE thingy SET thingyPlus2Res = '$plus2ToSave' WHERE drawDate = '$drawDate'");
    echo "Success";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Which script are you running with cron?

Comment: Do you actually have a JavaScript engine running in the cron job?

Comment: Apologies, i'm calling 'test.php'.

Comment: @garethdn: Show the `cron` line. *How* you call test.php will be significant.

Comment: how is your cron set up?  you know, unless you've done something specific on your server, your site is not going to run the same from a command line as it would from a browser - it won't run the JavaScript and it'll only return the text (none of the usual client-side processing will be performed).

Comment: Make sure simple_html_dom.php is in PHP's `include_path`.  When run from cron, it does not execute from the path you expect and that file may not be found.

Comment: I've updated my post with the cron line i'm using. In cpanel it is set to run every minute and from adding the results to a log file i'm getting the log appended with the html output every minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script you're trying to run contains Javascript - which is executed in a *browser*. Cron will execute the **PHP** script on the server, and send the output nowhere (as you're directing it to `/dev/null`).

There's nothing in that scenario that will interpret and execute the Javascript.

You need to essentially port the logic in your Javascript (which makes requests to the two related PHP scripts) to PHP. (*You could possibly run some server side javascript interpreter/php extension, but in this case that would seem a bit crazy.*)

Answer (score 2):

<s>If you're calling `test.php` via `wget` or similar, that tool</s> `php` doesn't have a JavaScript engine in it. So naturally any JavaScript-dependent features of the page won't run.

There *are* tools that will load the page and execute the JavaScript therein. They're called "headless" browsers. For example, [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), which is a headless browser based on WebKit with a JavaScript engine in it. There are also headless versions of Firefox and such.

You'd have your web server running as normal and point the headless browser at the URL for the page, which would both trigger the PHP (just as though the page had been requested by a browser) and process the client-side JavaScript in the page.